# Entity frame work Saving Many to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a news entity and I define a constraint to get the news based on their GroupID using GroupNews Table. Now when I add a new News because nothing is added to GroupNews table , News doesn't show up in the web page. I need to Add NewsID and GroupID to GroupNews Table.

[image]

I defined GroupNews in mywebContect.cs :

```
public class Groupnews : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Group> Group { get; set; }
    public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }

    public Groupnews()
        : base("MyDb")
    {
    }
}
   modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().
     HasMany(c => c.RelatedNews).
     WithMany(p => p.RelatedGroups).
     Map(
      m =>
      {
          m.ToTable("GroupNews");
          m.MapLeftKey("GroupID");
          m.MapRightKey("NewsID");
      });
```

also in News entity I defined :

```
  public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }
```

and the same thing for News. for saving GroupID and NewsID into GroupNews Table I add two lines to CreateEvent method in EventController:

```
        MeetingBoard.DAL.MeetingBoardContext.GroupNews.EventID = happening.EventID;
        Group p = new Group();
        MeetingBoard.DAL.MeetingBoardContext.GroupNews.GroupID = p.GroupID;
```

and here is CreateEvent method :

```
public void CreateEvent(string json_data)
{
    Event happening = Event.FromJson(json_data);

    if (happening.EventID == 0)
    {
        happening.CreatorID = UserHelper.GetCurrentUser().UserID;

        eventService.CreateEvent(happening);

        projectTag_service.AddProjectTag(happening);

        broadcastContext.Clients.triggerChange("event");
    }
    else
    {
        Event saved_happening = eventService.GetEvent(happening.EventID);

        saved_happening.Title = happening.Title;
        saved_happening.Description = happening.Description;
        saved_happening.Location = happening.Location;
        saved_happening.StartDate = happening.StartDate;
        saved_happening.EndDate = happening.EndDate;
        eventService.SaveEvent();

        projectTag_service.RemovesProjectTagsByEventID(happening.EventID);
        projectTag_service.AddProjectTag(happening);
        MeetingBoard.DAL.MeetingBoardContext.Groupevents.EventID = happening.EventID;
        Group p = new Group();
        MeetingBoard.DAL.MeetingBoardContext.Groupevents.GroupID = p.GroupID;
        broadcastContext.Clients.triggerChange("event_force");
    }
}
```

but still the GroupNews table is not updating and I could not see added News in the page.

Comment: where do you call `SaveChanges()`? as in `Groupnews.SaveChanges()`

Comment: in  EventService I have method SaveEvent()
        {
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }